# Azure DB & Schema Change Tracking

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm new to Azure and I have been asked to generate a daily report of added/changed databases, table or columns in Azure SQL Server. Specifically, we want to know when new datbases are created, new tables are added or existing ones altered and the same for columns. In non-Azure SQL Server you can use the Schema Changes History in standard reports but this is not available in Azure.

I have seen some suggestions you can do this with Extended Events but I've not found any resources to show how this can be done. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

DDL Triggers can really help you to keep track schema changes on your Azure SQL Database. Below is an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety   
ON DATABASE   
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE   
AS   
   PRINT 'Save change on a log'   
   SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

Database Auditing can help with schema changes and dropped objects. Below an example:

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseAuditing `
 -State Enabled `
 -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroupname" `
 -ServerName "ssqlinstancename" `  #ssqlinstancename.database.windows.net
 -StorageAccountName "strageaccountname" `
 -DatabaseName "dbname" `
 -AuditActionGroup 'SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP' `
 -RetentionInDays 8 `
 -AuditAction "DELETE ON schema::dbo BY [public]"
```

If you want to track DML operations also, you can use Temporal Tables but Database Auditing can help also:

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseAuditing -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroup"
 -ServerName "SQL Server Name" -DatabaseName "AdventureWorksLT"  
 -StorageAccountName "storageAccount" 
-AuditActionGroup "SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP", "FAILED_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP", "BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP" 
 -AuditAction "UPDATE ON database::[AdventureWorksLT] BY [public]"  
 -RetentionInDays 60
```